# Show that $o(gHg^{-1})=o(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Prove that $gHg^{-1}=\{ghg^{-1}|h \in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G$, $g\in G$. Show that $o(gHg^{-1})=o(H)$.**

Attempt:

As $e=geg^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$ then $gHg^{-1}$ is non-empty.
Let $x=gh_1g^{-1}$, $y=gh_2g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$, $h_1, h_2\in H$

then $xy^{-1}=\cdots=g(h_1h_2^{-1})g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$ as $h_1h_2^{-1}\in H$ ($H$ being the subgroup of $G$)

Therefore,
$gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup.

The problem is in 2nd part. I am unable to sgow that $o(gHg^{-1})=o(H)$. Please help me to solve the problem using the **elementary tools** of abstract algebra.

Comment: Hint: is the map $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ bijective?

Comment: $o(H)$ means the order of $H$?

Comment: @EclipseSun Yes.

Comment: Are homomorphisms elementary enough?

Comment: @egreg homomorphisms is not introduced yet.

Comment: Hint reminder: Read the hint of @Aimentoe. Also, the order of a group means its number of elements, also known as its "cardinality". So determining the order is really about set theory, which is even more elementary than abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Prove that the map
$$\phi: h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$$
is bijective.

Comment: How to show this? which one is correct $\phi: h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$ or $\phi: H \rightarrow  gHg^{-1}$?

Comment: I mean the first map: prove that it's injective and surjective.

Comment: How to prove it's injective and surjective?

Comment: It's very simple! Just use the definitions. For the injectivity prove that $\phi(h)=\phi(h)\implies h=h'$ and for the surjectivity: take $h'\in gHg^{-1}$ and find $h\in H$ such that $\phi(h)=h'$.

Comment: Injectivity is OK. Please explore the surjectivity.

Comment: @user1942348 $\phi(h)=h'$ implies $ghg^{-1}=h'\implies h=g^{-1}h'g=g^{-1}h'(g^{-1})^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Are homomorphisms elementary enough?

The map $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is a bijective homomorphism, so it maps subgroups onto subgroups and preserves the order of all subsets, in particular of subgroups.

The verification it is a homomorphism is easy; bijectivity follows from considering that the map $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ is its inverse.